# Find the number of div elements under a parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a jquery method that allows you to find the number of div elements under a parent node.

So say I have this set up

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

If I want to find the number of divs under parent it would be 2

or this

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child1"><div id="childer1"></div></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
</div>
```

It should give me 3.

Is there any method that does that for you?

Answer (score 8):

Yes. If you want *all* of them:

```
var divs = $('#parent').find('div').length;
```

or

```
var divs = $('#parent div').length;
```

If you just want the *immediate children*:

```
var divs = $('#parent').children('div').length;
```

or

```
var divs = $('#parent > div').length;
```

The variations involving "find" and "children" are handy in case your starting element is something for which you've already got a reference.

Comment: The second example makes it clear that he wants all of them, not just immediate children.

Comment: @Barmar yes I was pretty sure that was the case, but I figured the answer could cover that case for future readers :-)

Comment: you could have shown the context one too: `$('div','#parent').length` even it is not the best

Comment: @roasted I'm pretty sure that the jQuery guys have deprecated that form of the call.  I'll look for a reference. (Internally it's done via ".find()" anyway ...)

Answer (score 3):

This should do it:

```
var descendant_count = $("#parent div").length;
```

Answer (score 2):

Pure vanilla solution:

```
document.getElementById('parent').querySelectorAll('div').length;
```

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/V5wwS/)

**To note:** [**`querySelectorAll()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) is only supported in more recent versions of IE (as of **IE8+**).

Answer (score 1):

Without a library

```
document.getElementById("parent_div").children.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get number using length

```
$('#parent div').length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#parent').find('div').length;
```